# Grab selected ID from application in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml

I have a piece of code that will execute when the submit button is clicked

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("menu.xml");
XmlNode Quantity = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/MenuInfo/Meal/Quantity");
int qty = Convert.ToInt32(Quantity.InnerText);
// Deducting 1 from orginal quantity, you can use variable instead of quantity 1
Quantity.InnerText = (qty - 1).ToString();
//Finally you can retrieve modified xml from using doc.InnerXml
string modifiedXml = xml.InnerXml;
xml.Save("menu.xml");
MessageBox.Show("The order has been placed.");
Main nf = new Main();
nf.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

What this code does is when the user clicks submit on the application, the quantity element will be subtracted by one in the "menu.xml" file. However my issue is it is only doing it for meal 1. I currently have four different meals in the external "menu.xml" file and I want the programme to be able to recognise which meal was clicked on and subtract the quantity from that meal. For example, if the user clicks on Meal 1, than the quantity should be subtracted by 1, if the user clicks on meal 2 then the quantity should be subtracted from that meal instead. I know what needs to be done i.e grab the id, but I have no idea on how to do this, can somebody help me please? Hopefully this makes sense.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <MenuInfo>
        <Meal>
          <MealID>1</MealID>
          <Food>Meal 1 (Fish and Chips)</Food>
          <Price>£4.99</Price>
          <Time>25 minutes</Time>
          <Quantity>12</Quantity>
        </Meal>
        <Meal>
          <MealID>2</MealID>
          <Food>Meal 2 (Chicken and Chips)</Food>
          <Price>£3.99</Price>
          <Time>25 minutes</Time>
          <Quantity>12</Quantity>
        </Meal>
        <Meal>
          <MealID>3</MealID>
          <Food>Meal 3 (Saussage and Chips)</Food>
          <Price>£2.99</Price>
          <Time>25 minutes</Time>
          <Quantity>12</Quantity>
        </Meal>
        <Meal>
          <MealID>4</MealID>
          <Food>Meal 4 (Burger and Chips)</Food>
          <Price>£5.99</Price>
          <Time>25 minutes</Time>
          <Quantity>12</Quantity>
        </Meal>
    </MenuInfo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your search string can be customized further to find the Quantity node you're looking for

```
xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Meal[MealID = '4']/..//Quantity")
```

**Explanation**

- Searches the entire XML document for Meal nodes

  - Which have a child node named MealID

    - That has a value of 4 (In your case it's a variable)

      - Get the parent of this node (Meal in this case)

        - Get the Quantity node from anywhere under the parent

At this point, you should have the Quantity node you're looking for.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp